# Get max height - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I've a three paragraph with different content so what I need is first get the height of any paragraph then make the height of all paragraphs equal of the max height:

**Here my simple code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-container p').each(function (index, element) {
        alert($(this).height());
    });
})
```

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
.my-container{
    width:700px;
    margin:50px auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.my-container p{
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #00fb88;
}
.my-container p span{
    color:#00fb88;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">
        <p>
            <span>Paragraph One</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Paragraph Two</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Paragraph Three</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that flex is not supported by all browsers

Comment: Thank you it's not duplicate

Comment: Flex is supported by all major browsers and all currently supported versions of ie and yes it's a duplicate if you want to go the js way

Comment: my code is a testimonials slideshow so How to use flex with it, I think it's not possible because every paragraph will be in slide!!

Comment: Does your slider not have the option of equal height slides, most plugins I have seen for sliders will have the option somewhere.  If yours doesn't, this is a good slider you can use http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/codaslider/

Comment: $(".my-container p").each(function() {
var maxHeight = 0;
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
  }
  $(".my-container p").height(maxHeight);
});
 add this jquery live fiddle [ https://jsfiddle.net/fb8owyqn/ ]

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var highestBox = 0;
    $('.my-container p').each(function (index, element) {
   alert($(this).height());
       if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
          highestBox = $(this).height(); 
    $(this).height();
        }
    
    });
 $('.my-container p').height(highestBox);
})
 </script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not best performance but most simple like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var biggestHeight = 0; // change this number to define a min-height

    // loop over every box to find the height
    $('.my-container p').each(function (index, element) {
        var currentBoxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); // get each boxes height
        // compare the height and store as new biggest height if needed
        biggestHeight = currentBoxHeight >= biggestHeight ? currentBoxHeight : biggestHeight;
    });

    $('.my-container p').css('height', biggestHeight + 'px');
})
```

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
.my-container{
    width:700px;
    margin:50px auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.my-container p{
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #00fb88;
}
.my-container p span{
    color:#00fb88;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">
        <p>
            <span>Paragraph One</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Paragraph Two</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Paragraph Three</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would move your `$('.my-container p').css('height', biggestHeight + 'px');` outside the loop - then you won't be resetting the size everytime it changes

Comment: Thank you, but there are overflow why?

Comment: @caramba, you are not returning anything from the loop so how can it finish before all the heights are checked?  Also if it did finish before all the heights are checked, then it wouldn't matter whether that code is in or out, it would still have the same value of where the loop finished

Comment: Thank you very much pete and caramba :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
height = parseInt(style.height);
```

```js
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.my-container p').each(function(index, element) {
  var style, height;
  style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  height = parseInt(style.height);
  maxHeight = height >= maxHeight ? height : maxHeight;

});
$('.my-container p').css('height', maxHeight + 'px');
```

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.my-container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.my-container p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00fb88;
}

.my-container p span {
  color: #00fb88;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">

  <p>
    <span>Paragraph One</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi
    eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc
    nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Paragraph Two</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi
    eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Paragraph Three</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur adipiscing luctus massa nteger ut purus ac augue commodo commodo unc nec mi
    eu justo tempor consectetuer tiam.
  </p>
</div>
```